# Vh and vw when viewport initial-zoom does not equal 1

Tags: css, viewport, meta, viewport-units

I'm looking for an overlay to take up the entire screen.

```
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
```

The site I'm working on is not responsive and is set at 1000px wide.  I have the meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

set to load the site so it appears 1000px wide but use the device viewport as the vh/vw unit so that I can use media queries and javascript to remove/initialize/not initialize certain features.

The issue is that 100vh equals the viewport when the pixel ratio is 1:1 and not zoomed out therefore my 100vh/vw is much smaller than the physical viewport.

Is there a way to flood the viewport no matter what the scale/zoom level while retaining the ability to detect smaller screens?

As pointed out by @Benjamin Solum I should add that the issue arises on mobile browsers.

[image]

Comment: I hadn't heard of this so I tried it out over at codepen and it seemed to work fine (Chrome).  What browser are you zooming in with and how are you zooming?  Just increasing text size or zooming everything?  Have you tried %'s?

Comment: Pretty much any mobile browser

Comment: Ahhh, was thinking in terms of Desktop.  Would you be able to setup a Codepen/JSFiddle/etc. where you can replicate the issue that I could hit with my phone?  Just want to verify that I understand your question correctly.  Also, just to try it out, would `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1">` solve the issue?

Comment: Sorry for the delay: The initial-scale zooms in the browser so you only see the corner and the minimum-scale disallows zooming out.  Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n0rrmc9e/1/  Here's the light version to view on your phone: https://fiddle.jshell.net/n0rrmc9e/1/show/light/

Comment: Yea, I wasn't sure if preventing zoom out would solve your particular issue.  Shot in the dark :).  Ok, so other than setting `margin: 0;` on body to remove the white border on the top left, the red square covers the entire screen whether I zoom in or out on my android phone (Note 4).  Based on your CSS, that's what I'd expect.  What's happening in the fiddle exactly that's not working on your device?

Comment: Updated with screenshot from my Note 3. This is the result I saw on an iPhone 6 as well. Odd that your similar device. Not exactly sure what to make of that.

Comment: Hmm, I just dropped my cache and refreshed and my example is working as intended now.  The site I'm working on is incorrect but the example is working as intended. I'll take another look and see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: Interestingly enough, be returning to the site caused me to see it as your screenshot.  Will play around with it some more.

Comment: Call me crazy but when I originally linked the /show/light/ link it was just showing my example page but now it's showing the jfiddle shell with an iframe of my results.

Comment: I copied the fiddle into a pen: http://codepen.io/soluml/pen/rOaWEK just to be sure.  By setting `top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;`  instead of `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh;` I was able to consistently achieve the effect you'r egoing for on my Note 4.  I also set `margin: 0` for the body element to remove that extra padding. This is basically bjb568's answer, but I'd opt for `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute` in this case.

Comment: @bjb568's answer works.  Truthfully I could have sworn I tried this without success as it's something I do quite frequently but when I added it just now it worked.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To cover the entire screen, use absolute positioning:

```css
.overlay {
  /* For visibility */
  background: #f00;
  /* Position absolutely relative to viewport */
  position: absolute;
  /* Set edges to go all the way out to the viewport */
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">Hi!</div>
```

You don't need to mess with viewport metas or anything thing like that this way.

As Benjamin Solum said, you can make it position fixed if you want it to remain in the same position regardless of scrolling.

Comment: This works for me, though I'd replace `position: absolute` with `position: fixed`. I believe the effect the author is going for is to wanting to position relative to the screen's viewport and they probably don't want it to scroll.

Comment: The only down side is that I'm housing a google map element with a close button underneath it.  In an edge case where a user uses the space underneath the map to zoom in leaving only map on the screen they have no way to exit as zooming over the map will only zoom the map and not the viewport.  I can live with that though.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That the viewport width and height dimension are not adjusted after zoom is rather a topic of browser implementation.

Unlike width and height properties which seem to be more related to the DOM elements itself, I would consider browser implementation of vw and vh has to be changed.

But there might be reasons not to, like usecases where the current behavior is usefull. So I see low chance for a real solution for your case of zoom + non-responsive page.